# Diameter of "almost" always connected Erdős-Renyi graphs

Tags: random-graphs, diameter

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a random Erdős-Renyi Graph, i.e., $G\in\mathcal{G}(n,p)$.
It is well known that if $p=(\log n +c +o(1))/n$ with $c\in\Re$ then
$$
P(G \text{ is connected})=e^{-e^{-c}}\ .
$$

However, I found no information about the expectation of the diameter if $G$ is connected.

> My question is: Let $G\in\mathcal{G}(n,p)$ with $p=(\log n +c +o(1))/n$ and $c\in\Re$. What is the value of
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}(diam\ G \mid G\text{ is connected})
> $$

Is the result known? Or is it an open question? Any reference is welcome.

**Motivation:**

I'm performing simulations of several algorithms to compute the diameter of random graphs. Some of them are generated using the value of $p$ above. A graph is used only if it is connected. I would like to compare the results with the theoretical expectation.

Comment: Setting $c=1$, it appears numerically that $\mathbb{E}(\operatorname{diam} G | G \text{ is connected}) \leq \log n$ for large enough $n$ in an experiment I just ran. (Indeed, it appears to grow much slower than this.)

Comment: @cdipaolo Yes, I performed simulations with different values of $c$ and it seems that it is bounded by $O(\log n)$. I'm interested in a theoretical formula.